# PHP simplexml_load_string() "eats" some tags

Tags: php, simplexml

After hours of debugging my code i find out that simplexml_load_string() seem to silently remove all sub-entities within nodes values. To demonstrate the problem i made a little PHP script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channel>
  <element name="headline">
    <p>Line 1<br class="HardReturn"/>Line 2</p>
    <p>This is <b>bold</b> text</p>
  </element>
</channel>
XML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement");
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
print_r($errors);
var_dump($xml);
```

When run this in a shell i get this output:

```
Array
(
)
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["element"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "headline"
    }
    ["p"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "Line 1Line 2"
      [1]=>
      string(13) "This is  text"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `var_dump` skips the `<bold>` tags, but he `<bold>` tags are still there. To prove it, try

```
echo $xml->asXML() ."\r\n";
```

The output should be exactly the same as your input. Also try

```
$target = $xml->xpath("//b");
echo $target[0];
```

And the output is

```
bold
```

Comment: I don't get why the bolds are missing when i coerce it to string? I expected the node to have child-nodes of type type bold.

Comment: What do you mean by "when i coerce it to string"?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML hasn't "eaten" the nodes, it just isn't very good at showing them in debug outputs like print_r. The SimpleXML API is optimised for applications of XML as a tree of data, rather than text with markup like you have here.

In a more complex API such as the DOM, your first `p` element would be shown as having *three* child nodes:

- A text node containing "Line 1"
- A `br` element with an attribute `class`, value `HardReturn`
- A text node containing "Line 2"

However, SimpleXML doesn't have a separate object for "text nodes", instead it has an accessor for *the combined text content* of an element, when you cast to string. In this case, that combines the two text nodes, giving "Line 1Line 2". You can still access the `br` element, you just can't see where it fits relative to the text.

```
echo "String content: ", (string)$xml->element->p[0], "\n";
echo "Child element attribute: ", (string)$xml->element->p[0]->br['class'], "\n";
```

> `String content: Line 1Line 2`
> `Child element attribute: HardReturn`

With the second `p` element, there's a whole tree of nodes to represent:

- A text node contained "This is "
- A child element `b`

  - A text node *inside the `b` element* with the text "bold"
- A text node (in the `p` element) with the text " text"

Since the string representation only captures *directly contained* text nodes, the combined text content of the `p` element is just "This is " + " text".

```
echo "String content: ", (string)$xml->element->p[1], "\n";
echo "Child element string content: ", (string)$xml->element->p[1]->b, "\n";
```

> `String content: This is  text`
> `Child element string content: bold`

In both cases, we can see that all the nodes are still there, and get out the original XML:

```
echo "First paragraph: ", $xml->element->p[0]->asXML(), "\n";
echo "Second paragraph: ", $xml->element->p[1]->asXML(), "\n";
```

> `First paragraph: <p>Line 1<br class="HardReturn"/>Line 2</p>`
> `Second paragraph: <p>This is <b>bold</b> text</p>`

To work directly with the text nodes, you need to use a different API, such as [DOM](https://www.php.net/DOM); or, since this example appears to actually be HTML, look for an HTML-oriented library.